# Missing artifact org.wso2.esb:org.wso2.carbon.esb.common:jar:4.8.0

Tags: maven, wso2, wso2-esb

I was trying to integrate test cases for my WSO2 ESB classes and proxies.

I am following an example from WSO2 website, it is as shown in the link

https://docs.wso2.com/display/TA430/Writing+a+Test+Case+for+ESB

There is a test class which extends `ESBIntegrationTest` `(org.wso2.carbon.esb.ESBIntegrationTest)`. For which I figured out we need to add dependency maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.esb</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.esb.common</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After I add this, pom.xml is throwing error as 
`Missing artifact org.wso2.esb:org.wso2.carbon.esb.common:jar:4.8.0`

So what is the solution for this error ?

Comment: It is available in maven central https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wso2.esb/org.wso2.carbon.esb.common

Comment: Yes, same thing i've used as mentioned in the question. 
But after I add this dependency to pom.xml, i am getting this error - `Missing artifact org.wso2.esb:org.wso2.carbon.esb.common:jar:4.8.0`